# Switch `enable/disable touchpad` in function keys

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

I bought an MSI Prestige 15 where I installed Ubuntu with GNOME as the DE.

The symbol to enable or disable the touchpad is on the <kbd>F4</kbd> key, but to enable or disable the touchpad I have to press <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Is there a quick and easy way to fix it? I can't find the shortcut from the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: That is probably provided in "hardware": the OS has no access to these Fn keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use `fn + f4` to enable/disable the touchpad. First of all, you should remap your keyboard as follows:

1. Open or create the file: `~/.Xmodmap`
2. Add this line: `keycode  93 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle`
3. Reload the xmodmap: `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`

Now you can use `fn + f4` to toggle the touchpad.

More info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MSI_P15

Comment: This works well, do you know how to toggle the rotation for `f12` key too? I've read the article, but I can't understand how to execute the script